# JavaScript multiple incrementing variable solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, increment, dom-events

I have a variable `ver i = 1`.

I have a table as follows;

```
<table>
<tr class="testrow">
<td class="prev">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="data">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="next">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr class="testrow">
<td class="prev">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="data">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="next">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr class="testrow">
<td class="prev">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="data">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="next">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr class="testrow">
<td class="prev">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="data">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="next">&nbsp;</td>
</tr class="testrow">
<tr>
<td class="prev">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="data">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="next">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The table may have more rows. I want a variable to increase value by 1 when I click `next` and decrease by 1 for `prev`. This can be done easily. But I want some variable which is row dependent. When I click`next` in first row, the variable value should be 2, but it should not change when I click either `next` or `prev` in any other row. Also this should be the case in all other rows. The minimum value of variable should be 1.

It will be helpful if someone provide me a fiddle with the variable displayed in the middle cell of each row. Note that in this demo, it should not be something to `++` or `--` the text or data in the middle cell.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/5TPCK/1/) is my fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use [jQuery.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) to store the variable in each row, changing it when the user clicks prev/next:

```
$(function() {

    $(".testrow").each(function() {
        var $row = $(this);
        // set the initial value  
        $row.data("currentIndex", 1);

        $row.find(".prev").click(function() {
            $row.data("currentIndex", $row.data("currentIndex") - 1);
            alert("currentIndex: "+$row.data("currentIndex"));
        });
        $row.find(".next").click(function() {
            $row.data("currentIndex", $row.data("currentIndex") + 1);
            alert("currentIndex: "+$row.data("currentIndex"));
        });

    });

});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5TPCK/12/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('table tr .next').click(function() {
    alert($(this).closest('tr').index());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/5TPCK/2/

Btw, `</tr class="testrow">` is horribly wrong - it should only be `</tr>`.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you keep an array of these counters (this would work if the number of rows is known beforehand and static)? Otherwise you could attach the counter to each `<tr>` element using the jquery `data()` function.

See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/